# Control the playback speed of a Video Player using Slider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video-player

How can I simply control the playback speed of a video player in Unity.
Right now I have this code but the problem is I can only debug the output in the console log, is there a way to do it on the actual Video Player?

Video Player Script:

```
   public Slider mySlider;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mySlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ValueChangeCheck(); });
    }

    public void ValueChangeCheck()
    {
        Debug.Log(mySlider.value);
    }
```

Here is my UI

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but if I'm not mistaken you need to make sure the video has been prepared (essentially fully loaded) in order to change the playback speed, take a look at the official Unity documentation for the Video Player [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html)

```
public Slider mySlider;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    mySlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { AdjustSpeed(); });
}

public void AdjustSpeed()
{
    videoPlayer.playbackSpeed = mySlider.value
}
```